# Is there a way to send message to telegram with python without using a bot?

Tags: python, telegram

Sorry, if it's a dumb question.
I just want to know for sure yes, or no.

Comment: Do you want to send a message from your own account?

Comment: @Aynos Yes. That's exactly what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

**It is possible to create a self-bot for telegram.**
To get an inspiration on how to do it, I would suggest you dig into [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/kdrag0n/pyrobud).